how to deploy a xamarin app in a device, using the device manager
I have an existing xamarin application, I have several devices in the device manager. The code builds fine. But when I click to deploy it I get an error.
I clicked on the green arrow on top:

I expect this to build and deploy, but somehow the deployment fails.
After a while, I get the following:

then after a while it gives an error but it doesn't say much.
I was hoping to get it deployed
